# Null Pointer Exception RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a `NullPointerException` and I can't see where I messed up my code. :)

This is my code:

```
public class VideosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideosAdapter.VideoViewHolder> {

    private List<Video> videos;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;

    public static class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        RelativeLayout videoLayout;
        TextView videoTitle;
        TextView channelTitle;

        public VideoViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            videoLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.videoLayout);
            videoTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.videoTitle);
            channelTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.channelTitle);
        }
    }

    public VideosAdapter (List<Video> videos, int rowLayout, Context context) {
        this.videos = videos;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public VideosAdapter.VideoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new VideoViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VideoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.channelTitle.setText(videos.get(position).getChannelTitle());
        holder.videoTitle.setText(videos.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return videos.size();
    }
}
```

And this is my LogCat :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
     at tactivityplayinc.streamtube.Adapters.VideosAdapter.getItemCount(VideosAdapter.java:67)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:2938)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2619)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16271)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4945)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16271)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1560)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16271)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4945)
     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16271)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4945)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16271)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4945)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16271)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4945)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16271)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4945)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16271)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4945)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2501)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16271)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2182)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1330)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1541)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1227)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4995)
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't realize what I didn't initialize or something and I can't go any further without fixing this problem.

Comment: Check List<Video> videos variable. it might be null or empty list.

Comment: Your `videos` object is null. Make sure the object is not null when initializing the adapter, or add a method to update the object when desired